# Hiredis cluster with Redis Stack modules

Tags: c, redis, in-memory-database, redis-cluster, hiredis

I’m using hiredis cluster in order to use cluster feature with Redis. In latest hiredis cluster, there is one python script to generate command file. To do this, we need to give Redis path as an argument to the script. There is no problem till here. But I want to use redis search so I’m loading that modules via redis conf. Then I can use redis search modules features via redis-cli. But I can’t use this commands with hiredis cluster so in commands path there is no JSON named as redis search commands. How can I add this commands to redis commands path as a json? Or is there any other way to use redis Stack modules with hiredis cluster?